# How to observe a node's child items based on a variable of that child node in Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase

I am creating a messaging app, and using Firebase as backend. I know how to observe for added children of a given node using `observe` method and `.childAdded`. my data is structured as

- Node

  - ChildNode1

    - Key1:value1
    - Key2:value2
    - Key3:value3
    - timestamp:Int
  - ChildNode2
    .
    .
    .

is there a way of observing the parent node but only retrieve childnodes that have a timestamp value greater than a particular value? so that I won't need to retrieve all the child nodes and only keep the ones that meet the requirements?

This is the code I use to retrieve the childnodes:

```
let userMessagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("DataStructure").child("ListOfItems").child("ParentNode")
observerHandler = userMessagesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    //My code would go here
    
    //This works as required AFTER all the data is downloaded
    //In other words, once the previous (not needed) childnodes and those I want are downloaded
    //I can use it for subsequent and newly added childnodes
   
    //However, I don't want to retrieve all the childnodes everytime this runs
    //I want to only retrieve childnodes that were added after a particular time
    //I save the timestamp as Int of seconds in the childnode.
    //I also save the timestamp of last retrieve childnode in the app
    //What I ideally want is to retrieve all childnodes after the timestamp
    //saved in the app (something like any childnode with timestamp greater than the timestamp int in the code)
}, withCancel: nil)
```

Would it work if I add the observer to a query, and set the query to retrieve the childnodes with timestamp after my local timestamp I saved?

Comment: Please share some code on how you retrieve the childnodes.

Comment: @Koen I added the code and some comments about it.